# Billingsley Theorem 25.9 - Filling up holes

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, proof-explanation

\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\dom}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXNvJ.png){\operatorname{Dom}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}

I'm reading the Book Billingsley of Probability and Measure. I am struggling with understanding some parts of the proof of Theorem 25.9:

**Theorem 25.9.** For every sequence ($F_n$) of distribution functions there exists a subsequence $(F_{n_k})$ and a nondecreasing, right-continuous function $F$ such that $\lim_k F_{n_{k}}(x) = F(x)$ at continuity points $x$ of $F$.

**PROOF.** An application of the diagonal method [A14] gives a sequence ($n_{k}$) of integers along which the limit $G(r) = \lim_k F_{n_k}(r)$ exists for every rational $r$. Define $F(x) = \inf[G(r): x < r]$. Clearly, $F$ is nondecreasing.

To each $x$ and $\varepsilon$, there is an $r$ for which $x < r$ and $G(r) < F(x) + \varepsilon$. If $x < y < r$, then $F(y) < G(r) < F(x) + \varepsilon$. Hence F is continuous from the right.

If $F$ is continuous at $x$, choose $y < x$ so that $F(x) – \varepsilon < F(y)$; now choose rational $r$ and $s$ so that $y < r < x < s$ and $G(s) < F(x) + \varepsilon$. From $F(x) – \varepsilon < G(r) < G(s) < F(x) + \varepsilon$ and $F_{n}(r) < F_{n}(x) < F_{n}(s)$ it follows that as $k$ goes to infinity $F_{n_{k}}(x) has limits superior and inferior within $\varepsilon$ of $F$

[Screenshot from Billingsley](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXNvJ.png)

**My questions are the following:**

(1) On the last sentence of the second paragraph proof. How does he get the conclusion? I don't see connections between it and my definition:

> My definition of right continuos at $x_{0}$ is the following:
>
> $$F(x_{0}) = \lim_{x \downarrow x_{0}}F(x)$$
> It means that for a monotonically decreasing sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n \ in \N}$ that goes to $x$ we have that $F(x_{n})$ tends to $F(x)$.

(2) I don't understand how to get the conclusion we have by the end to see that the limit exists. Do you have a way to get it?

**Rewritting the Proof**

Using ideas from answers!!

An application of the diagonal method [A14] gives a sequence ($n_{k}$) of integers along which the limit $G(r) = \lim_k F_{n_k}(r)$ exists for every rational $r$. Define

$$F(x) = \inf[G(r): x < r]$$

***F is nondecreasing*** Let $x,y \in \dom{F}$ such that $x < y$. Notice that, from the hypothesis, we have the inclusion of sets:

$$[G(r)\,:\,x < r] \subset [G(r)\,:\,y < r]$$

By infimum properties, we have that:

$$\inf[G(r)\,:\,x < r] \leq \inf[G(r)\,:\,y < r]$$

By definition of $F$ we get that:

$$F(x) \leq F(y)$$

As we wanted!

***F is right continuous*** Let $\{x_{n}\}_{n \in \N}$ a decreasing sequence that converges to $x$. We want to verify that $F(x_{n}) \to F(x)$

Comment: I added the theorem, copied from the book

Answer (score 1):

1. 

Fix $x$ and take decreasing sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ so that $x_{n}\to x$. We wish to prove $F(x_{n}) \to F(x) $. In order to do so we must show that for any $\varepsilon$  there is a large enough $n_{0}$ so that $$|F(x)-F(x_{n})|\leq \varepsilon$$
For all $n\geq n_{0}$. We take $r$ as in

> To each $x$ and $ε$, there is an $r$ for which $x<r$ and $G(r)<F(x)+\varepsilon$. If x<y<r, then $F(y)<G(r)<F(x)+ε$

Beacuse $x_{n}\to x$ there exist a an $n_{0}$ such that $x_{n}-x < r-x$  for all $n\geq n_{0}$ (We are omitting the absolute value here because we know $x_{n}\geq x$). Then for any such $n$ we have $x\leq x_{n}\leq r$, so $$F(x_{n})\leq F(x)+\varepsilon$$
Because $F$ is non-decreasing we have $$F(x)\leq F(x_{n})$$ so
$$|F(x_{n})-F(x)|=F(x_{n})-F(x)\leq \varepsilon$$
For every $n\geq n_{0}$.

2.

> Let $G_{x}(r_{1})$
> the first infimum and $G_{y}(r_{1})$
> the second.

Careful there, remember you are dealing with *infimums* here and not *minimums*, at most you can take $G_{x}(r_{1})$ such that $G_{x}(r_{1})-F(x)\leq \varepsilon$

> Then since the sequence of integers is increasing and each function is a distribution function, then $G_{x}(r_{1})≤G_{x}(r_{2})$
> .

I don't exactly see how this follows from what you wrote, you have $x<r_{1}$ and $y<r_{2}$ but no way to know $r_{1}<r_{2}$.

Your approach is not entirely wrong but I suspect that on your way of fixing that last bit of your argument you'll stumble upon the much simpler fact in that if $x<y$
$$\{G(r):y<r\} \subseteq \{G(r): x<r\}$$
so $\inf \{G(r): x<r\} \leq \inf \{G(r):y<r\}  $

3.

So far you have that for any $\varepsilon$ there are rationals $r \leq x \leq s$ such that $$F(x)- \varepsilon \leq G(s) \leq G(r)\leq F(x) + \varepsilon $$

Because $F_{n}(r) \leq F_{n}(x) \leq F_{n}(s) $ we have
$$ F(x)-\varepsilon \leq G(r) = \lim\limits_{k \to \infty}{F_{n_{k}}(r)}\leq \liminf\limits_{k\to \infty}{F_{n_{k}}(x)} $$
And
$$\limsup\limits_{k\to \infty}{F_{n_{k}}(x)} \leq \lim\limits_{k \to \infty}{F_{n_{k}}(s)} = G(s) \leq F(x)+\varepsilon $$

Because $\varepsilon$ was chosen arbitrarily we can conclude that
$$F(x)\leq \liminf\limits_{k\to \infty}{F_{n_{k}}(x)} \leq \limsup\limits_{k\to \infty}{F_{n_{k}}(x)} \leq F(x) $$

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer... On the (1) Are not we suppose to take an arbitrary sequence that is monotonically decreasing and that goes to $x_{0}$. Is this reasoning equivalent to yours, I don't quite understand yet.

Comment: I am grateful for this point of view of (2) by inclusions, I didn't see it before. Thank you! Since it makes sense to me, I added it.

Comment: Both definitions are indeed equivalent, the reasoning is the same as to why sequential continuity (i.e.  $x_{n} \to x$ then $f(x_{n}) \to f(x)$ ) and the usual $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity are equivalent.

Comment: Take any decreasing sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ such that $x_{n}\to x$. Fix $\varepsilon$ and and take $r$ as in the first part of the proof of the theorem. Because  $x_{n}\to x$, for large enough $n_{0}$ we have $x-x_{n} \leq r$ so that $|F(x_{n})-F(x)|=F(x_{n})-F(x)\leq \varepsilon$ for every $n\geq n_{0}$. So $F(x_{n})\to F(x) $.

Comment: In your last comment, I am trying to understand the steps... How do you choose $r$, is it such that $F(x) "=" G_{x}(r)$ (ed. For any $\varepsilon > 0$, $G_{x}(r))< F(x) + \varepsilon$?

Comment: Also I don't catch how do you conclude that $x - x_{n} \leq r$. I was trying to thing a about it and I thing you are using, in the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of convergence of sequences, the $\varepsilon = r$ and getting the conlusion. Also using the fact that the sequence is decreasing to delete absolute values. Am I right?

Comment: Finally, I don't see how you conclude from last reasoning the conclusion about |F(x_{n}) - F(x)| \leq \varepsilon. I understant your first step (deleting the absoulte value) but not the second.

Comment: On (3), May you help me? I don't understand how do you get the inequality $F(x) - \varepsilon \leq G(r)$ and $G(s) \leq G(r)$

Comment: I edited the answer to the first question to better fit the definitions you've been using, I hope It's more clear now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146296/discussion-between-fzan-and-topology-g).